# Is this step in computing the conditional expectation of a product correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Given a sequence of independent variables {$X_i, i \in \mathbb{N}$} with $X_i$ ~ $N(0,1)$ for all $i$ and a Poisson distributed random variable $Y$ with parameter $1$ independent of the aforementioned sequence. We want to compute:

$\mathbb{E} [X_{Y+1}X^2_{1}X_{2} | X_{1}]$

My steps were the following:

1) First we can take out the $X^2_{1}$ due to the fact that we are conditioning on $X_1$. This leaves us with:

$X^2_{1}*\mathbb{E} [X_{Y+1}X_{2} | X_{1}]$.

2) This is where I get stuck because our variable $Y$ can also have value $1$ which would give us $X^2_{2}$ within the expectation. However, there is also a probability that it is not equal to $1$. This gave me the following idea; we can turn the expectation above into a sum of the probabilities as follows:

$X^2_{1}*\mathbb{E} [X_{Y+1}X_{2} | X_{1}]$ = $X^2_{1}(\mathbb{P}(Y=1)*\mathbb{E}[X^2_{2}]+(1-\mathbb{P}(Y=1))*\mathbb{E}[X_{Y+1}]*\mathbb{E}[X_{2}])$.

This could then be further solved using rules for the moments of a standard normal distribution. My question is, is this step correct? Can i write the expectation as the sum of a probability times expectation?

I must add that this question is for a homework exercise so it would be preferred to not give the final answer immediately but rather a tip on how to get there.

Comment: You have the right idea. The justification for the steps you're using is the tower rule - for any $X, Y$ and function $f$ it holds that $\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y)] = \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbb{E} \left[ f(X,Y)\mid Y \right]\right]$.
Also, a small issue - a Poisson RV can also take the value $0$, so you can have $X_{Y+1} = X_1$ as well, for which the factorisation $\mathbb{E}[X_1 X_2 |X_1] = \mathbb{E}[X_1] \cdot \mathbb{E}[X_2]$ is incorrect, although you'll get the same answer in this particular case.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm curious though, is the step where I write the conditional expectation as the sum of a probability times an expectation correct or does this step need a more specific setting in order to be true?

Comment: I think you're using the independence of various quantities pretty strongly in that, so it isn't quite generic. It may be a useful exercise to write out a general form of this equality using the tower rule, and then explicitly noting where you use independence.